# Модель работы WebKit'a с запросами

Tags: webkit, javascript, http, браузер

У меня есть серверное приложение. Обозреватель (браузер) делает к нему запросы. Часть запросов приложение держит в подвешенном состоянии, те ждет реакции от ядра системы, после чего, в ответе отправляет клиенту результат. Когда идет работа только с одним представлением (открыта одна вкладка обозревателя) все нормально. Но при открытие нескольких вкладок только первые 2 нормально отображаются, остальные подгружаются на половину и виснут, а при закрытии первых двух, вторые две догружаются до конца. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это поведение не только webkit-а. Все браузеры имеют ограничения на максимальное число открытых соединений, на каждый хост и в целом. По умолчанию на один сервер может быть открыто от 2-х до 8-и соединений (в HTTP/1.1 RFC рекомендовалось не более двух).